# How to access default NSOPenPanel actions?

Tags: swift, macos

Which actions are fired when user uses default NSOpenPanel from Main Menu? How to get the selection from it without creating NSOpenPanel in the code?

Comment: I'm not  sure I understand your question. Could you try adding a concrete example of what you want to do, or rephrase?

Comment: He doesn't know that either. I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A.

> Which actions are fired when user uses default NSOpenPanel from Main Menu?

There is no `NSOpenPanel` in the main menu. There is a menu item "Open…"

The automatism you might "feel" is implemented project dependently. But it is not there automatically. I think that some points has to be clearified:

a. Open Menu Item

The menu item "Open…" sends and only sends the action message `openDocument:` to the first responder. "Open…" does *not* open a panel, window dialog or $whatever.

Please get some [information about first responders and the responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW2). It is a pity, that even the responder chain is one of the core concept of Cocoa, it is very unknown.

b. Open Panel

*If* you choosed to have a document based application, when you created the project, some additions are made to your project. In particular,

- An instance of `NSDocumentController` is instantiated automatically.
- This [instance becomes a part of the responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW9).

Since `NSDocumentController` implements `-openDocument:`, it will catch the action message and

- run an open panel
- creates an instance of `NSDocument`. (More precise: of the subclass you selected as the document class.)

B.

> How to get the selection from it without creating NSOpenPanel in the code?

- Create a document-based app and let Cocoa do what it has to do. The base implementation of Cocoa matches 99 % of the cases and can be customized highly.
- Do not create a document-based app: Handle the action message yourself, open a open panel yourself, after finishing that, create the instance of a document class and so on.